# Convert.ToDateTime(D) compared to (DateTime)D

Tags: c#

If I have a value **D** and want to ensure it is type datetime then is there a difference between the following?

1. `DateTime dtm = Convert.ToDateTime(D)`
2. `DateTime dtm = (DateTime)D`

1 is a conversion whereas 2 is a cast? (I assume in certain respects 2 is a *lighter* operation?)
When should I use 1 rather than 2?

---

**Edit**

(context of question)

**D** is from a cell in a `DataTable`. What I'm doing is finding any cells that are dates (via the `datatable.columnname`) and then apply the `ToOADate` function to the result before moving it to xl. So if `dr` is my `DataRowView` then I have either of the following alternatives:

```
//Convert
DateTime dtm;
dtm = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[i - 1]);
xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, i].value = dtm.ToOADate();

//Cast
DateTime dtm;
dtm = (DateTime)dr[i - 1];
xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, i].value = dtm.ToOADate();
```

Comment: @Oded good question - it's a cell in a DataTable - in SQL-server the field that D is extracted from is DateTime; I'll add this (and a bit more) to the OP

Comment: @Oded added a small explanation of the question context

Comment: When you say they might be a date, does that mean a string representing a date or a `DateTime` object, or something else?

Comment: @Oded In SQL-Server the field is a Datetime. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Convert.ToDateTime` has several overloads that will convert other types to `DateTime`. It should be used when you're converting an instance that isn't a DateTime to a DateTime instance. You could also use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) (if you're trying to parse a string representation).

`(DateTime)D` attempts to directly cast an instance to `DateTime`. If the instance isn't already a `DateTime` prior to the call, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: +1 sounds like because `dr[i - 1]` is already a datetime from the datatable that I'll be best using cast as it's quicker

Answer (score 1):

By using the "Convert" class you can actually convert between different types. E.g. you can convert a String into a DateTime.
Casting only works on the same types. So you can not cast a String into an Int32 as this would raise a cast exception.

Regarding your example:
If the content of D is always of the DateTime type then you should prefer casting it because a cast is very fast.
In case you don't know what type is inside D (maybe because it's of Object type) you might want to prefer converting it as this is more elegant than just plain casting because this method allows you to set the DateTime also by String (Date String) or by Int32 (ticks).